# Android - Open running services page(in developer options)

Tags: android

How can I open Running services settings?
Is it possible to open this page using Intent or Method invoke?
[Running services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuPVK.png)

Answer (score 0):

This only works on 5.1 and below.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.RunningServices"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Somehow on 6.0 this call opens the configure apps page showing title running services. May be there are some extra flags that need to be passed.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this in Android 6+?